# How to add user_id in create form

Tags: laravel, controller, eloquent

I am studying an eloquent relationship and I want to create a post for specific user. I want to add `User_Id` in create form

Below are my code snippets:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <form method="post" action="{{route('articles.store')}}">
    @csrf
        <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Başlık</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="title" placeholder="Başlık">
        </div>
        @if($errors->has('title'))
            <span class="text-danger">
                {{$errors->first('title')}}
            </span>
        @endif
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Post İçeriği</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="body" placeholder="İçerik" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        @if($errors->has('body'))
            <span class="text-danger">
                {{$errors->first('body')}}
            </span>
        @endif
        <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Kaydet</button>
     </form>
    </div>
@endsection
```

and my article model is like this;

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Article extends Model
{
   protected $fillable=[
  'title','body','user_id'
];

 public function user()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
 }

}
```

And here is my controller;

```
public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
{
    Auth::user();
    $article =  new Article();
    $article -> title=$request->get('title');
    $article -> body=$request->get('body');

    $article->save();

    return redirect()->route('articles.index');
}
```

But at the end, I am getting below error:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a 
   default value (SQL: insert into `articles` (`title`, `body`, `updated_at`, 
  `created_at`) values (Merhaba, Bu post id değeri 1 olan user tarafından 
   yazıldı., 2018-05-03 06:55:45, 2018-05-03 06:55:45))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take current logged in user ID from Auth user in store procedure.

```
public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
{
    Auth::user();
    $article =  new Article();
    $article -> user_id=Auth::user()->id;
    $article -> title=$request->get('title');
    $article -> body=$request->get('body');

    $article->save();

    return redirect()->route('articles.index');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
{
    Auth::user();
    $article =  new Article();
    $article -> title=$request->get('title');
    $article -> body=$request->get('body');
```

> $article ->user_id=$request->get('user_id'); // add this line

```
    $article->save();

    return redirect()->route('articles.index');
}
```

Comment: This is insecure though, people can post messages as other users by changing the hidden input value. Look at the answer below from @Tanvir which proposes a better solution.

Comment: Yes @Tuim, you are right. I posted this answer as per the blade template have the content. Otherwise it is good to take the user id from Auth::user();

Answer (score 1):

You can send the user id along with others post data like others answers did. But since you studying how eloquent relationship works, then why not using it to save the article model.

Create article relationship inside `User` model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{  
   .........
   .........

   // Since user can have many articles, then i assumed you need
   // hasMany relationship here, otherwise please change accordingly.
   public function articles()
   {
     return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
   }

}
```

And in your controller(it will automatically add foreign key to `Article` model):

```
public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
{

  $user = Auth::user();

  $user->articles()->create($request->only(
     'title',
     'body'
  ));

  return redirect()->route('articles.index');
}
```

And lastly, remove `user_id` input field from form(no longer needed as the article will saved by relationship of authenticated `User` model):

```
<!-- remove this -->
<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ Auth::user()->id }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting user in

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

use this id

```
$article -> user_id = $user->id;

public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $article =  new Article();
    $article -> title=$request->get('title');
    $article -> body=$request->get('body');
    $article -> user_id = $user->id;


    $article->save();

    return redirect()->route('articles.index');
}
```

Or

else you can get user_id in post request from form(you can use hidden field for user_id in your form for this) and just pass it

```
$article -> user_id=$request->get('user_id');
```